# Bound CheckboxElement does not update its UI correctly

Tags: binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

To have a bindable checkbox-list in iOS with MvvmCross, I created a view-class that holds a checkbox element, that is bound to the item viewmodel:

```
public class CheckListItemView : BaseView
{
    public CheckListItemView()
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CheckListItemView, CheckListItemViewModel>();

        var item = new CheckboxElement();

        set.Bind(item).For(v => v.Value).To(vm => vm.IsChecked).TwoWay();

        set.Apply();

        this.CheckboxElement = item;
    }

    public new CheckListItemViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return base.ViewModel.As<CheckListItemViewModel>(); }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public Element CheckboxElement { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case the binding is not too reliable: I have a button that checks all items checked and one that un-checks all boxes.

```
foreach (var checkListItemViewModel in checkList)
{
    checkListItemViewModel.IsChecked = value;
}
```

If I keep pressing those two buttons for a time, at some point the UI does not update the checked state correctly. The values in the background are correct, though.

Comment: Is MVX putting any warnings out to the console? Check the output window there may be some hints there.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are telling the UI it is being changed.  Are you calling RaisePropertyChanged event when you change the state?

Comment: Yes, I do this. It also works if I click on the buttons very slowly. If i "stress" the app by clicking fast on "Select all" and "Select none", at some point it stops working. It looks to me like some threading problem, but I don' know how to handle this.

Comment: What happens if you do a RaiseAllPropertiesChanged after your loop that sets all the buttons?  I think we might need more code... Also as the first commenter suggested, do you get any warning messages or errors in the stack trace?